# Launch app in background, start it to run over Cellular and collect data

Tags: android, service, background

I am new to android and trying to launch an app in the background (e.g. speedtest) and ask it to start it by clicking on it and run on the background and send the data results back as an output. I am expecting all this to happen in background. The code which I have written launches the app in the foreground.

```
private static final String TAG = "MyService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! MyService Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("org.zwanoo.android.speedtest");
    if (intent != null)
    {
        /* we found the activity now start the activity */
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        /* bring user to the market or let them choose an app? */
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+"org.zwanoo.android.speedtest"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");  
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}
```

}